# Each time a class is ran it will open a new frame

Tags: java, class, jframe

I have added an actionlistener to a jmenuitem that invokes a class, which reads an excel file and opens a jgraph in a jframe.
I have also added another actionlistener to a different jmenuitem to invoke the same class for the same exel file but a different excel sheet (different int parameter). However when I run my main frame, and I click on the menu items, I can only open one of them at a time. And I have to close one to open the other. I need to change it so that whenever a user clicks onit, every time a new different frame/window will appear.

```
public class ReadExcel {

//reads excel file sheet and saves some strings in arrays
public static ArrayList<String> RM = new ArrayList<String>() ;
...




public static void excel(String excelfile, Integer sheetno) {
...
}
}
```

---

```
public class graphgen extends JFrame {

//creates a graph based on ReadExcel arrays


public graphgen() {

        gen();

    }

    public void gen(){

    }

public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        graphgen frame = new graphgen();
        p2.add(graphComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setSize(1600, 1200);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Main class that has the menu bar:

```
   menuItem = new JMenuItem("MenuItem1",KeyEvent.VK_B);
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2) {

                                    new ReadExcel();
                                 ReadExcel.excel(".xls", 0);
                                    new graphgen();
                                    graphgen.main(null);
                                }
                            });     
                        subsubmenu1.add(menuItem);


    menuItem = new JMenuItem("MenuItem2",KeyEvent.VK_C);
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2) {

                                    new ReadExcel();
                                   ReadExcel.excel(".xls", 1);
                                    new graphgen();
                                    graphgen.main(null);
                                }
                            });     
                        subsubmenu1.add(menuItem);

public static void main(String[] args)
            {


                GUIquery frame = new GUIquery();
                p.add(graphComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setJMenuBar(GUIquery.createMenuBar());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(true);
                frame.setSize(1600, 1200);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at graphgen.gen(graphgen.java:645)
    at graphgen.<init>(graphgen.java:62)
    at GUIquery$9.actionPerformed(GUIquery.java:713)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please post `graphgen` as that is where your issue possibly lies

Comment: ``new ReadExcel(); ReadExcel.excel(".xls", 0); new graphgen(); graphgen.main(null);`` This looks really weird! Why create instances of those classes, when you call static methods?

Comment: also how are `ReadExcel` and `graphgen` related? more code please

Comment: Added more code sorry for not being clear. @vandale

Comment: Now I can open the 2 frames at the same time without error, but the one goes blank when the other opens

Answer (score 0):

(A little guessing is involved.)

You do all the work in `actionPerformed` methods which are called by the event dispatcher thread; that is the thread that is responsible for handling events and drawing the UI. So while you are doing work within such a method no other event (like button or menu click) can be handled.

To allow this you need to put the work into a separate `Thread`, e.g..

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event2) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ReadExcel();
            ReadExcel.excel(".xls", 0);
            new graphgen();
            graphgen.main(null);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

If this opens a new window depends on the code within graphgen. If this code opens a new window for every call to the static `main` method and if the code handles Swing threading correctly then it will do this but we can't look into that code.

Calling other Java code by calling a static `main` method is always suspicious. You should have a public, documented API that you could use.

Comment: Nope it wont let me run them both at the same time and open them in different frames. I get the following errors: Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NumberFormatException: multiple points
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at graphgen.gen(graphgen.java:645)
 at graphgen.<init>(graphgen.java:62)
 at GUIquery$9$1.run(GUIquery.java:737)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 @his

Comment: Read and understand the exception: a double value cannot be parsed.

Comment: It is this line, but I dont get why there should be a problem init. double value = Double.parseDouble(ReadExcel.totalarray);

Comment: I put it as public static and the error is gone. However now I can open the 2 frames at the same time without error, but the one goes blank when the other opens. @qqilihq

Comment: Sorry, but you have several problems at once (and I picked only one which was dubious in itself) that you need to separate and debug separately. But debugging (or teaching how to do this) is out of the scope of SO.

Answer (score 0):

for the error you showed it is there because at some point in your code (`at graphgen.gen(graphgen.java:645)` ) you are parsing a `String` and converting it to a double. However, the string is not a valid `double`- because it has multiple decimal points (.) -so it is throwing an error. You should print out (via `System.out.println()` ) what ever you are trying to convert and analyze what is wrong with the string.

I would recommend that you take all your source code, zip it up, and use a filesharing service such as [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com) or [Google Drive](http://www.google.com/drive/) and post the link as the code pertinent to the error is no here